# How to draw mathematical equation in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making a math game in libgdx. I have Generate random problems and store in ArrayList.
    Now I want to draw these Mathmatical expressions on screen Scree, Actually SCreen have   3   part

```
                 ---------------------------------------------
                |     Score                    Sound          |
                |                                             |
                 ----------------------------------------------
                |   3-1=2                                     | 
                |                                             |
                |                           8+9=4             |
                |                                             |
                |                                             |
                |                                             |
                |                                             |
                |              5*4=20                         |
                |                                             |
                |                                             |
                 ----------------------------------------------
                |  Virtual keyboard of                        |
                |  numbers (0-9)for user input                |
                 ----------------------------------------------
```

Anyone guide me how I can draw like this these expression are moving top to bottom.

Comment: use Label and table. See this https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the power of `Action` class. Just create `Label's` and attach `MoveTo` (or `MoveBy`) action to them. Please read more info about actions [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Actions).

```
Stage yourStage = ...
Group root = yourStage.getRoot();

// create some label
final Label mathExpression = new Label("3-1=2", yourSkin, "labelSkinName");
// set initial position, could be random
mathExpression.setPosition(randomXPosition, topPosition); 

// create sequence action, where actions are run one by one
SequenceAction sequence = new SequenceAction(); 
// add simple action that moves actor down by topPosition with 4sec to the sequenca
sequence.addAction(Actions.moveBy(0, -topPosition, 4)); 
// add Runnable action that will be run after that to the sequence
sequence.addAction(Actions.run(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    void run()
    {
        // this code will be run after label fall, for example, remove it
        mathExpression.remove();
    }
}

// attach your actions sequence to the label
mathExpression.addAction(sequence);

// for example, attach label to root
root.addActor(mathExpression);
```

You could create those labels one by one and actions will take care of them.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, I am not using scene2D.

Comment: good time to start using it then @SandeepTiwari

Answer (score 0):

Use a table that contains 3 tables: headerTable, equationsTable, footerTable:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.settFillParent(true);
Table headerTable = new Table();
Table equationsTable = new Table();
Table footerTable = new Table();
table.add(headerTable).expandX().height(headerHeight);
table.row();
table.add(equationsTable).expandX().(equationsHeight);
table.row();
table.add(footerTable).expandX().(footerHeight);
```

Now ofcourse you need to define the heights yourself. Really all you need now is a Label and a TextButotn. 
For the label create a LabelStyle and add it to a label like this:

```
LabelStyle labelStyle = new LabelStyle(font, Color);
Label scoreLabel = new Label("score", labelStyle);
```

Now just add the labels to the respective tables and play around with cells and paddings to get your desired result, use this guide for tables https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout:

```
headerTable.add(scoreLabel).left();
headerTable.add(soundLabel).right();
```

The equations would be just labels that you can add to the equationsTable and change the text with:

```
label.setText(newEqationText);
```